# How do I remove this recessed light bulb?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting, bulb

This is a small recessed light in my new house (still figuring out all the nuances of it). How do I get the bulb out of this recessed fixture in order to replace it?

It looks like there is some holder around the outside, but not sure how it works.

[image]

Comment: Once you've done as others recommend, push the bulb upward with a little bit of force (like on an automotive tail light).  If it moves upward a bit, then it is probably a push-and-twist type (exactly like an automotive tail light). Turn it left 1/8 of a turn and it should come free.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'll try out the suggestions and report back once I get free moment (aka toddlers go to bed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet you have Halo H7LVICT.

The entire 6" trim is held up by two metal springs that allow the trim to remain snug in place but also allow it to be pulled down if necessary.

However, just to replace the bulb you'd actually just pull out the little mr16 socket which snaps in and out.  A 12v 50w mr16 would be the bulb replacement.

See [H7LVICT Low Voltage Baffle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://site.electricsuppliesonline.com/ebay/documents/halo/H7LVT.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjQh6i-ldzTAhUBbiYKHZ_3DmMQFgg2MAM&usg=AFQjCNGDIAW7n5XbT4OY0x5K1_FGEQcIsQ&sig2=GNizVqTGdb2VGm5ALtu11g)

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what it was. Tugged on the trim exactly as you said and out popped a 12V 50W MR16 bulb. I plan to replace this with an LED equivalent, recommendations?

Comment: Phillips mr16 LED 50watt equivalent --  for the the price and looks great.

Answer (score 1):

That conical thing in the ceiling and it's white flange that fits against the ceiling will typically pull down and be removed. It should have springy wire fingers that fit up into part of the fixture. Once you have that out of the way the bulb will be easy to access.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the "trim ring" (white part on the ceiling surface) pulls down, often taking the black interior part with it - then there are spring legs you can squeeze to release from slots in the fixture "can" to get that out of your way.

If someone painted aggressively and ignorantly you may need to break some paint to get the trim ring to move.

Answer (score 0):

Push up and twist on the bulb - there is a by pin connection for the lamp - sometimes these things have a rubber tool like a dart gun dart - you stick it to it , push and twist. Take a look around your new home - the builder may have left it in one of the drawers or with a kit of stuff.

[That is probably a GU10 base bulb.](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Philips-50-Watt-Halogen-MR16-GU10-TwistLine-Dimmable-Light-Bulb-6-Pack-415760/202775188)